# Abbreviations and full stop--how to avoid double dots?

Tags: macros, punctuation

I have trouble with macros expanding to an abbreviated expression. Say I have `\WHP` which expands to "`with high prob.`" (artificial example). I want to avoid the dot after the abbreviation colliding with full stops later on, like

> "We concluded that hypothesis holds \WHP."

which should *not* expand to

> "We concluded that hypothesis holds with high prob.."

but simply end with one full stop.

Answer (score 23):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\WHP{with high prob\@ifnextchar.{}{.}}% test of next token 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\WHP

\WHP.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or better yet, make the `\@ifnextchar.{}{.}` bit a separate macro and use it in the definition of any abbreviation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will be my \xdot macro from now on. Oh, and for the sake of good typography I'll throw a \@ in there after the dot.

Comment: How can I use this in the glossaries package for the \gls{...} and related commands, for abbreviations and the like which may end in a dot.

Comment: @ADP: show an example

Comment: @Herbert, I have posted a question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119537/avoiding-double-dots-in-glossaries-package

Comment: @Ubik, what's \@?

Comment: @Ariel: `\makeatletter` makes `@` to a normal letter. So the question what's `\@` is wrong ... ;-) the _name_ of the macro is `@ifnextchar`

Comment: @Herbert, sure, but Ubik wrote "I'll throw a \@ in there after the dot.", so I wondered what that is.