# Acronyms without double dots using glossaries

Tags: macros, punctuation, glossaries, acronyms

I want to typeset my acronyms with abbreviating dots with, for
instance, `P.C.A.` standing for `principal component analysis` and use
macros for them.
[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/abbreviations-and-full-stop-how-to-avoid-double-dots)
provides a trick to avoid double dots when the acronym is at the end
of a sentence so that `This could be done with a \pca.` gives

> This could be done with a P.C.A.

and not

> This could be done with a P.C.A. .

Now, i would like to combine this approach with the acronym related
commands of `glossaries`.
Thus, I defined an acronym with this command

```
\newacronym{pca}{\pca}{principal component analysis}
```

and then use it with `\gls{pca}`

```
This could be done with a \gls{pca}.
```

However, the `glossaries` command add some characters between \pca and
the full stop so that the trick mentioned before does not work and I
get a double dot.

Any idea how I could deal with that?

Here is a minimal working example. The `xspace` package and command
can be removed ; they are intended to conform to the english usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{xspace}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\abren}[1]{%
    \@ifnextchar{.}%
        {#1}%
        {#1.\@\xspace}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\pca}{\abren{P.C.A}}

\newacronym{pca}{\pca}{principal component analysis}

\begin{document}
This could be done with a \pca. %good

This could be done with a \gls{pca}. %good

This could be done with a \gls{pca}.%awkward
\end{document}
```

Comment: Acronyms are usually typeset *without* periods also in order to avoid problems like this one. The dots don't add anything that can't be obtained by a uniform typographical appearance of acronyms.

Comment: @egreg Still, the problem is real in some languages where dots are common practice in acronyms, or where there are "complex" abbreviations – a set of truncated words with dots between them, for instance. But I am afraid this calls for own acronym commands that no package offers out of the box.

Comment: I am writing in french. In this language, the rule of thumb is that   acronyms pronunced as words do not have dots while those pronunced as sequence of letters have some. Their are no unified rules about this particular point and usage vary a lot from one source to another. However, from what I could gather, dots are indeed useful and recomended in some context.

Comment: @AlfredM. I Thought it was something like that (I write in French too). This does not solve your question at all if you need to use the `glossaries` package for other reasons, but [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39000/10119) is how I solved it with a (very ugly) `biblatex` hack. It could probably be improved by writing the .bib file automatically. Note that I opted for dots in all of the acronyms that should be in the list of abbreviations (the ones pronounced as words are well known and seldom explained, like UNESCO).

Comment: Relevant discussions about the use of dots in acronym in french can be found [here](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/accolade-allemand.html#Acronyme).
The length of them shows how fuzzy the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xspace}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{pca}{P.C.A.}{principal component analysis}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgls}[1]{%
  \expandafter\csname ifglo@#1@flag\endcsname
    \gls{#1}\expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \gls{#1}\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {\@ifnextchar.{\get@sf}{\xspace}}%
}
\def\get@sf#1{\spacefactor\the\sfcode`#1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This could be done with a \pgls{pca}. Just to see the first usage.

This could be done with a \pgls{pca}. And the spacing?

This could be done with a P.C.A\@. And the spacing?

This could be done with a \pgls{pca} or not.

This could be done with a P.C.A. or not.

\end{document}
```

The lines with the explicit `P.C.A.` are just to show that the spacing is good. The macro `\pgls` checks whether we are at the first usage of the acronym. More complicated things, such as using the expanded version at other times can be obtained by the ordinary commands provided by `glossaries`.

[image]

The macro checks first of all whether the acronym has already been used. In this case the conditional `\ifglo@pca@flag` is true. So when it's false we don't have to do anything special other than issuing `\gls{pca}`. The `\expandafter\csname ifglo@#1@flag\endcsname` is just to use the argument: with `\pgls{pca}` it becomes `\ifglo@pca@flag` as desired.

If the conditional is true, then the tokens after the final `\fi` are evaluated. This is the check whether a period follows; if there is a period, then `\get@sf` is executed, otherwise `\xspace` (necessary because `\@ifnextchar` gobbles spaces).

In case there is a period, `\@ifnextchar` doesn't remove it and it becomes the argument to `\get@sf`, which expands to `\spacefactor\the\sfcode`.\relax`, thus setting the desired space factor.

Comment: I (and for sure others, too) would have appreciated if you explained in more in detail how the macro works. Just to enlighten us (me). It seems as a useful algorithm. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The spacing is not right if the command `\frenchspacing` is used.
In a french document, one has to be careful to use `pgls` only at sentences end and `\gls`elsewhere.

Comment: @AlfredM. I don't think the spacing is wrong: the macro adds the current spacefactor associated to a period, which `\frenchspacing` sets to 1000.

Comment: That should be some other line in my preamble then. I'll get back here if I find it.

Comment: The problem was caused by commenting the line loading the xspace package by mistake… Took some times to find because it did not throw an error.

Comment: This, however, also removes the period when the acronym has no trailing period, i.e. ```This picture shows the headquarters of the \pgls{UNO}. It is located in New York.``` becomes ```This picture shows the headquarters of the UNO It is located in New York.```

Comment: @greektex The assumption was that acronyms have letters separated with periods.

Comment: There is a solution developed for the scenario that not all acronyms have a trailing period: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119537/avoiding-double-dots-in-glossaries-package?rq=1