# Avoiding double dots in glossaries package

Tags: punctuation, glossaries

I would like to incorporate the suggested solution by Herbert, that can be found [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/abbreviations-and-full-stop-how-to-avoid-double-dots), within certain glossary records.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\fs}{\@ifnextchar.{}{.}}% test of next token 
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{pg}{
    name={pg.},
    description={pg.},
    first={pg.},
    firstplural={pp.},
    plural={pp.}
}
\newglossaryentry{fig}{
    name={fig.},
    description={fig.},
    first={fig.},
    firstplural={figs.},
    plural={figs.}
}


\begin{document}
    as can be seen in the \glspl{fig} on the following \gls{pg}.
\end{document}
```

Which typesets without issue, however it creates a double dot at the end of the sentence.

A solution that I had in mind would be to try and put the defined macro `\fs` into the glossary records, however errors get returned, ie, the following causes the above to not compile:

```
\newglossaryentry{pg}{
    name={pg\fs},
    description={pg\fs},
    first={pg\fs},
    firstplural={pp\fs},
    plural={pp\fs}
}
```

Another approach could be to modify the `\gls{...}` and similar commands, to check if the evaluated record ends in a '.', and if so, replace by the `\fs` macro, but there are many commands as part of the glossaries package, not sure how to do it this way.

How can this be achieved. I use glossaries as a means to host many such abbreviations on a document-wide basis.

Comment: To get compilable code use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\fs}{\@ifnextchar.{}{.}}`.  However, this doesn't help with eating the dot though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires adding a level above `\gls` and similar commands. One can redefine them, rather than use new commands, this is left as an exercise.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries,amsthm}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter
% define a non space skipping version of \@ifnextchar
\newcommand\fussy@ifnextchar[3]{%
  \let\reserved@d=#1%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \def\reserved@b{#3}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\fussy@ifnch}
\def\fussy@ifnch{%
  \ifx\@let@token\reserved@d
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@a 
  \else
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
  \fi
 \reserved@c}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Gls}[1]{%
  \gls{#1}\fussy@ifnextchar.{\@checkperiod}{\@}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Glspl}[1]{%
  \glspl{#1}\fussy@ifnextchar.{\@checkperiod}{\@}}

\newcommand{\@checkperiod}[1]{%
  \ifnum\sfcode`\.=\spacefactor\else#1\fi
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{box}{
  name=box,
  description=box,
  plural=boxes,
}

\newglossaryentry{pg}{
  name={pg.},
  description={pg.},
  first={pg.},
  firstplural={pp.},
  plural={pp.}
}
\newglossaryentry{fig}{
  name={fig.},
  description={fig.},
  first={fig.},
  firstplural={figs.},
  plural={figs.}
}


\begin{document}
As can be seen in the \Glspl{fig} on the following \Gls{pg}.

As can be seen in \Glspl{box} or in \Gls{box}.

As can be seen in the \Glspl{fig}, on the following \Gls{pg}, we have commas.

As can be seen in \Glspl{box}, or in \Gls{box}, we have commas.

\end{document}
```

Note that `amsthm` is essential; actually what's needed is how it redefines `\frenchspacing` so a unique space factor code is set by a period and not the generic 1000.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding `\fs` to the definitions won't work as the text generated by commands such as `\gls` can be quite deeply embedded within the internal workings. At the very least, it will be followed by the unsetting of the first use flag. There are two alternatives:

**Method 1:**

Keep track of which entries have a dot (such as including the dot in the label to remind yourself) and don't add the sentence dot. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pg.}{
    name={pg.},
    description={pg.},
    first={pg.},
    firstplural={pp.},
    plural={pp.}
}
\newglossaryentry{fig.}{
    name={fig.},
    description={fig.},
    first={fig.},
    firstplural={figs.},
    plural={figs.}
}

\begin{document}
    as can be seen in the \glspl{fig.} on the following \gls{pg.}
This sentence refers to the \gls{fig.}['s] caption.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

**Method 2:**

Don't add the dot to the definitions. Instead define a command that will add the dot where required. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter

  \newcommand{\abbrev}[2][]{%
    \new@ifnextchar[%
     {\@abbrev{#1}{#2}}% get the final optional argument
     {%
        \new@ifnextchar.%
        {\@gls@{#1}{#2}[]}% end of sentence found
        {\@gls@{#1}{#2}[.\spacefactor=1000]}% not end of sentence, add abbreviation dot
     }%
  }

  \def\@abbrev#1#2[#3]{%
    \new@ifnextchar.%
    {\@gls@{#1}{#2}[#3]}% end of sentence found
    {\@gls@{#1}{#2}[.#3]}% not end of sentence, add abbreviation dot
  }

  % Similar code for plural:

  \newcommand{\abbrevpl}[2][]{%
    \new@ifnextchar[%
     {\@abbrevpl{#1}{#2}}% get the final optional argument
     {%
        \new@ifnextchar.%
        {\@glspl@{#1}{#2}[]}% end of sentence found
        {\@glspl@{#1}{#2}[.\spacefactor=1000]}% not end of sentence, add abbreviation dot
     }%
  }

  \def\@abbrevpl#1#2[#3]{%
    \new@ifnextchar.%
    {\@glspl@{#1}{#2}[#3]}% end of sentence found
    {\@glspl@{#1}{#2}[.#3]}% not end of sentence, add abbreviation dot
  }

  % Do likewise for any other required variation

\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{pg}{
    name={pg.},
    text={pg},
    description={pg},
    first={pg},
    firstplural={pp},
    plural={pp}
}
\newglossaryentry{fig}{
    name={fig.},
    text={fig},
    description={fig},
    first={fig},
    firstplural={figs},
    plural={figs}
}

\begin{document}
    as can be seen in the \abbrevpl{fig} on the following \abbrev{pg}.
This sentence refers to the \abbrev{fig}['s] caption.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of result]

The second method correctly adjusts the space factor.